# Type Mismatch Error in Word, but not in Excel or PowerPoint

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm programming a custom chart add-in for Word that should behave the same as add-ins I've already done for Excel and PowerPoint. The code is very similar in all three programs, but I'm getting a baffling error in Word that doesn't occur in the other 2 programs.

Excel (works just fine):

```
Sub AddTextboxToChart()
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim oChtShp As Shape
    Dim oLegShp As Shape
    
    sChtName = ActiveChart.Name
    ChtShpName$ = Right(sChtName, Len(sChtName) - InStrRev(sChtName, " ", Len(ActiveSheet.Name) + 1))
    Set oChtShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ChtShpName$)
    Set oChart = oChtShp.Chart
    
    Set oLegShp = oChart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 100)
    oLegShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

PowerPoint (also works fine):

```
Sub AddTextboxToChart()
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim oChtShp As Shape
    Dim oLegShp As Shape
    
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).HasChart Then
        Set oChtShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        Set oChart = oChtShp.Chart
        
        Set oLegShp = oChart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 100)
        oLegShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Word (errors on "Set oLegShp" line):

```
Sub AddTextboxToChart()
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim oChtShp As Shape
    Dim oLegShp As Shape
    
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).HasChart Then
        Set oChtShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        Set oChart = oChtShp.Chart
        
        Set oLegShp = oChart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 100) 'This line errors with Type Mismatch
        oLegShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Excel and PowerPoint behave as expected, but Word errors out with a Type Mismatch when it tries to set the shape reference to an added text box. Any ideas or workarounds?

If you try to run the code, create a sample chart in Word, then set it to be floating in front of the text. Otherwise, Word sees it as an Inline Shape, which is a whole other can of worms.

I'm running Version 2205 (Build 15225.20288 Click-to-Run) under Windows 10.

(Edit) A kludge to get around the bug:

```
        oChart.Shapes.AddTextbox msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 100
        For x = 1 To oChart.Shapes.Count
            If oChart.Shapes(x).Left = LegLeft And oChart.Shapes(x).Top = LegTop Then
                oChart.Shapes(x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)
            End If
        Next x
```